# How to change the arrow location attribute in BubbleView library?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using this library :

[BubbleView Library](https://github.com/lguipeng/BubbleView)

Question is:

How can i change the Arrow Location Attribute programmatically?

I need to change from Left to Right Arrow Location.

Please Help..

Comment: Share the code you have tried so far. Please post only the relevant code.

Comment: In the **Usage**, what are these? `app:arrowPosition="14dp"`, `app:arrowLocation="right"`, `app:arrowCenter="true"`. And for programatically: https://github.com/lguipeng/BubbleView/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=arrowPosition&type=

Comment: Mr Hyde, Can you show me example of code, because i am still learning.

Comment: can we make like this? private void addOrRemoveProperty(View view, int property, boolean flag){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        if(flag){
            layoutParams.addRule(property);
        }else {
            layoutParams.removeRule(property);
        }
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    },                        But this one is for RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

they are already shown in **Usage**

```
<com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello BubbleTextVew"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:arrowWidth="8dp"
        app:angle="8dp"
        app:arrowHeight="10dp"
        app:arrowPosition="14dp"
        app:arrowLocation="right"
        app:arrowCenter="true"
        app:bubbleColor="#7EC0EE"/>
```

`app:arrowLocation` support `left right top bottom`

`app:arrowCenter` will make `arrow center` in the edge

**UPDATE :**

If you want to set Arrow programmatically then use [this dependency](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout) instead yours.

here you can change Arrow position in java as you want like below.

```
 bubbleLayout.setArrowDirection(ArrowDirection.TOP);
```

Comment: Hi, I want to try changing it by java, not by XML sir.